# Angular-strap - Want specific selected item remove all previous selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Im recently implemented angular-strap and Im using its multiple select.
It works fine but now i want to have one option that says "All" and if clicked it will remove all other previous selected options..

Cant figure out how to do it as all i have to play with is the list of selected items.. There is no single last selected which would be useful. How could i solve this?
Tryed to play with watch and a onChange.

Looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" placeholder="Filtrera på kategori" ng-model="selectedCategories"         data-html="1" data-multiple="1" max-length="6" data-animation="am-flip-x" ng-options="category.Id as category.Name for  category in categories" bs-select>
   Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

**JS controller**

```
orderContrl.controller('addProductInternalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'productItemCategories',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, productItemCategories) {
        init();
        $scope.selectedCategories = [productItemCategories[0].Id];
        $scope.categories = productItemCategories;

        function init() {

        };

        $scope.$watch("selectedCategories", function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            console.log(oldValue);
        });

        $scope.changeSelectedCategories = function (selectedCategories) {
            if (selectedCategories.length > 1 && selectedCategories[0] == -1)
                selectedCategories.shift();
            //else {
            //    angular.forEach(selectedCategories, function (item) {
            //        if (item == -1)
            //            saveProductToOrder(item);
            //    });
            //}
            if (selectedCategories.length > 1 && selectedCategories[0] == -1)
                selectedCategories.shift();
            console.log(selectedCategories);
        };

        // Closes modal and sets chosen treeview value
        $scope.ok = function () {

        };
        // Closes modal and cancels
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    }]);
```

Comment: you should consider passing this options via data-attributes on the directive: `data-all-none-buttons="true"`